# Update Jquery to a later version but not for edit pages

Tags: theming, javascript

I am trying to update Jquery on my website (to Jquery 1.8.3) for the front end only.

I am using the following code below and it works fine. However, as I am using my theme for node/edit pages, the code breaks some of the contrib modules that are displayed on the node/edit pages.

How can I limit the code so it doesn't effect node/edit pages?

Here is the code I am using:

```
function mytheme_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  // exclude backend pages to avoid core js not working anymore
  // you could also just use a backend theme to avoid this
    $scripts = drupal_add_js();
    $new_jquery = array(drupal_get_path('theme', 'mytheme') . '/scripts/jquery-1.8.3.js' => $scripts['core']['misc/jquery.js']);
    $scripts['core'] = array_merge($new_jquery, $scripts['core']);
    unset($scripts['core']['misc/jquery.js']);
    $variables['scripts'] = drupal_get_js('header', $scripts);

}
```

---

Steps I have tried:

**1. Applying an if statement.**

I have tried wrapping the code in the following if statement which comes from [Method 4 on this page](https://drupal.org/node/1058168):

```
if (arg(0) != 'admin' || !(arg(1) == 'add' && arg(2) == 'edit') || arg(0) != 'panels' || arg(0) != 'ctools') {
}
```

However, this code seems to disable Jquery on all pages.

**2. Using [Jquery Update](https://drupal.org/project/jquery_update)**

This module brakes functionality on admin/contrib modules. It also seems to have permission errors.

**3. [Jquery Multi](https://drupal.org/project/jqmulti)**

I can't seem to get this module to work. 
(The module requires you to either move your Javascripts to the libraries folder (which isn't an option for me due to my workflow) or to add a number suffix to your scripts (which again isn't an option due to work flow).

Thanks for any help that can be offered.

Comment: Dev version of Jquery Update has this functionality

Comment: @xurshid29 The dev version doesn't seem to work for anonymous users.

Comment: So use [my patch](https://drupal.org/node/888334)?

Comment: @big_smile don't know how are you installing it, but in my project it works perfectly for both anonymous and authenticated users

Comment: @Mołot Thanks! However, on the thread it says the patch isn't going to be committed to the module, so it's not a long term solution.

Comment: @xurshid29 I'll try it again. However, I have tried it on a clean install in the last week and it doesn't work for anonymous users.

Comment: For long term solution you need to see the issue thread  xurshid29 mentioned. It works all right for me, too. My patch is just an easy alternative.

Comment: @xurshid29 Also, it would also cause the newer jquery to be active on Node/edit pages, which I don't want to happen.

Comment: https://drupal.org/node/1539276 and maybe https://drupal.org/node/1969244

Comment: @big_smile What is newer jquery? Do you mean 1.5 version?

Comment: @xurshid29 I need to update to Jquery 1.8.3

Comment: big_smile, @xurshid29 could you maybe take your talk to [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/327/drupal-answers)?

Comment: @Mołot The only draw back about the two links you posted is that they don't seem to have been acknowledge by the maintainers, so I am not sure if they will be long term solutions.

Comment: So see this older one https://drupal.org/node/1524944 but it's Closed (fixed), the ones I linked seem to be it's follow-ups.

Comment: @Mołot After reviewing the threads, I would rather not use Jquery Update. The module seems to be in a very bad state requiring patches to work. Many of these patches have either been rejected or ignored by the developers. Maybe in the future it might improve, but at the moment, it doesn't seem like a long term solution.

Comment: Your choice, but if you will start to redevelop that wheel again, you risk getting all the same problems. I'm using it for years without any significant issue I wasn't able to patch myself (the one I linked you to). Anyway, good luck on your chosen path of action.